# How to allow users to unsubscribe from organic groups?

Tags: organic-groups

In D6, more often than not users change their mind and want to unsubscribe from groups that the have subscribed. How can they do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this link:
http://sitename.com/og/unsubscribe/gid/uid

gid = group id
uid = user id

====== second option =======

Go to "Manage membership" or "My membership". click on "Leave this group"